# How to update child state when button in parent component is clicked

Tags: reactjs

in child component I want to update the state when user clicked on button available in parent component and I've keep track of state value as this state is also affect by other code as well so  I was thinking to use useEffect() hook but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

```
child component:

const [sentimentButtonValue, setSentimentButtonValue] = useState(false);

return(
<>
{sentimentButtonValue}
</>
)

parent Component:

const handelTableCardOpen = (idx) => {
// when this function call, want to update child 'sentimentButtonValue' state value
    console.log(idx);
    setSelectedRow(idx);
  };

<Button key={idx} onClick={() => handelTableCardOpen (idx)}> Click </Button>
```

Comment: Lift the child state to the parent component, and pass the state down to child as props. When the state is updated in the parent, the child will rerender with the new value. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

as others have stated, you need to life the state up, **BUT JUST IN CASE** you have a special case where you really need it

```
const Child = React.forwardRef((_, ref) => {
  const [sentimentButtonValue, setSentimentButtonValue] = React.useState(false);
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    whatEver: sentimentButtonValue,
    setWhatEver: setSentimentButtonValue,
  }));
  return <>{sentimentButtonValue.toString()}</>;
});

const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = React.useRef();
  const handelTableCardOpen = () => {
    childRef.current.setWhatEver(!childRef.current.whatEver);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handelTableCardOpen}>Click</button>
      <Child ref={childRef} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to lift the state from the child to the parent component, and then pass that state as a prop to the child:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [sentimentButtonValue, setSentimentButtonValue] = useState(false)

  const yourFunction = () => {
    setSentimentButtonValue(newValue);
  } 

  <Button
    sentimentButtonValue={sentimentButtonValue}
    onClick={yourFunction}
  >
    Click
  </Button>
}
```